# How replace either of two words using a regexp to find them?

Tags: regular-expressions

Text

```
How are you?
I'm just fine.
```

I need to add some suffix to the next words: `are` and `fine`.

I try this:

```
\(are\)|\(fine\)
```

but it doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: No code. I need this for replace-regexp command. I updated my post

Comment: I think you're after `C-M-% are\|fine RET \&-test RET !`

Comment: @Basil Please convert your comment into an answer and maybe stress that the or operator in Emacs regexps is `\|` and not the Perl version `|`.

Comment: @Tobias Done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I try this:
>
> `\(are\)|\(fine\)`

This is valid Elisp regexp syntax, but it's probably not what you were after. In particular, alternations are delimited by `\|` in Elisp syntax, not `|` as in POSIX ERE and Perl syntax. In Elisp regexps, `|` is a literal vertical bar character. See [`(emacs) Regexp Backslash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html).

In addition, the grouping constructs `\(...\)` are unnecessary in this case (though they don't do any harm), since you are subsequently referring to the whole match `\&`, not the first or second group `\1` or `\2`, respectively. See [`(emacs) Regexp Replace`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html).

So what you are probably after is <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>`are\|fine`<kbd>RET</kbd>`\&-test`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

The question has been kind of answered, but, I am going to focus on the "add a suffix" part.  Here we go:

run the command:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace`

which for vanilla emacs is normally mapped to: <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>

you will be prompted with:
`Query replace regexp:`
and type in:
`\(are\|fine\)`

and hit <kbd>return</kbd>

next, you will be prompted:
`Query replace regexp \(are|fine\) with:`
and you type:
`\1 boop the snoot`

and hit <kbd>return</kbd>

you will be prompted (`y or n`) on each match if you want to do the replacement.

with this, you will convert:

```
How are you?
I'm just fine.
```

to:

```
How are boop the snoot you?
I'm just fine boop the snoot.
```

so what just happened?

the brackets `()` in the matcher are telling the regex system to store that part of the match (in you case, `are` or `fine`).  In the replacer, we are telling emacs to replace the matched text with the first matched text (`\1`) *and* a new suffix `boop the snoot`.

You can also have multiple match groups:
`\([a-z]+\) \([0-9]+\) \(A-Z]\)`

and reference them in a replacer:
`\3 \1 \2`

which would rearrange this:
`boop 8 SNOOTS`

to:
`SNOOTS boop 8`

the slashes `\` are escape characters that are sometimes required to alter the meaning of a character (take me literally).